# How to check authorization when HTML5 file called in JSF project

Tags: html, jsf-2, authorization, userid, phaselistener

I define a PhaseListener for to check authorization in JSF project. But it doesn't work for HTML5. Even if I add to url=*.html for servlet mapping in web.exml, it doesn't work for HTML5. Because JSF2 does not support some tags of HTML5. Such as canvas etc.

What can I do to check authorization when HTML5 file called in JSF project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should in first place not have used a phase listener for the job at all, but a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). A phase listener runs only on JSF requests, i.e. only requests which matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`. A phase listener is a clumsy approach for the sole purpose of authorization checking.

Here's a concrete kickoff example of how such a filter could look like, assuming that you've stored the logged-in user as `User` object in the session:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        User user = (session != null) ? session.getAttribute("user") : null;
        String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";

        boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(loginURL);
        boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);

        if (user != null || loginRequest || resourceRequest)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(loginURL);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying now it

Comment: Hi,
I had done login in userBean(ManagedBean) for jsf. So I don't know how user attribute is set. Can I set with jquery.post() -> servlet or userBean ?

Comment: By the way, filter is working, thank you. I try to write `request.getSession().setAttribute("user", u);` in userBean

Comment: Hi,

I investigate can Managedbean be reached in loginfilter. Result of It can be reached. So I did it. Thank you BalusC